# Design pattern for accumulate / flush messages

Tags: java, design-patterns, amazon-s3

currently we have a publish / consumer service where the consumer writes the messages received to AWS S3. We are currently writing more than 100.000.000 objects per month.
However, we can group this messages based on some rules in order to save some money.
These rules, can be something like:

- If we have received 10 messages of the User 1 -> group them, and
  write to S3.
- If we have received < 10 messages of the User 1 and the elapsed time since the last message is more than 5 seconds, flush to S3.
- If the "internal" queue, is bigger than N, start to flush

What we don't want is to eat our memory... Because of that, I am looking of what would be the best approach from design patterns perspective, taking into consideration that we are speaking about a high loaded system, so we don't have infinite memory resources.

Thanks!,

Comment: An important piece of information missing: How many DIFFERENT users are possible? How big is the amount of users generating these 100M objects/month?

Comment: Well, the number of total users is around 300 right now. Some of them generate just a couple of messages per day, and others generate thousands per second during peaks.

Comment: So if you have 300 users only, why do you bother about eating up memory? What prevents you from creating 300 monitoring object (for each user one) and check there the status of messages for each user?

Comment: The idea here, is accumulate the messages of each user for a time, and write all the accumulated messages once. For example, if one user, produces 100 messages per second, and the system accumulates during one minute, it will write only once 6000 messages (grouped in one object). In terms of AWS S3, this is a big saving (since the price per PUT operation is only once, instead of 6000 puts).

Comment: Well, but you wrote in your original post that you flush every 10 messages from a single user, not 6000. It's not memory consuming to keep up to 10 messages for 300 user (=> max 3000 messages in memory at a single moment). Please clarify your flushing rules then.

Comment: Yes, 10 messages, 100, we don't have define it... no matter: my question here is "Design pattern for accumulate / flush messages", not technical requirements.

Comment: But the concrete technical requirements *are* relevant! Why would you build a scaffolding for a wall 0.5m high? Simply keep to about 300 monitoring objects for each of your 300 users, and each of them will be filled up to 10 messages before you flush them. Keep a timestamp of the last message for each of your users and compare the timestamps with the current time.

Comment: Ok: this is the situation: we want to save write request to Amazon S3. We have users that can generate up to 1000 messages per second, and others 1 per minute. All this messages come from a queue, and we want to acummulate them per-user.
The policies to fire when to write to S3, are two:
1-When the acumulated is bigger, than let's say 100 messages, flush to S3.
2-When the there is an elapsed time of, let's say, 60 second, flush to S3.
I have already done a solution... my question was more oriented to explore if there is any Software Pattern to this case. Nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, based on your further explanation in comments, there are *related* algorithms called [Leaky bucket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_bucket#The_Leaky_Bucket_Algorithm_as_a_Queue) and [Token bucket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket). Their primary purpose is slightly different but you may consider using some modification - especially you may consider viewing the "leaking droplets out of the bucket" as the regular commit of all the messages of a single user in a bunch flush to S3.

So more or less modification like this (*please read the description of the algorithms first*):

1. You have a bucket per user (you may easily afford it, as you have only about 300 users)
2. Each bucket is filled by messages coming from each user
3. You regularly let each bucket leak (flush all the messages or just a limited bunch of messages)

I guess that it somehow follows what your original requirement might have been.

Comment: Thank you Honza, I guess this is the solution